# Modifying an existing Stacked Column chart with EPPlus

Tags: asp.net, epplus, epplus-4

So this is my question, i have an excel report with a nicely formatted stacked column report. Is it possible to find and edit the existing chart as apposed to creating a new one. The number of series points is dynamic ( the values would be on the report). so i would like to be able to alter the range for the series on the existing chart.

Comment: Can you post code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: i really dont have anything now, i cant find any code where someone modifies an existing chart